# pre calculate tar size

Tags: amazon-s3, tar, archive

I'd like to pre-calculate the final size of the tar file without actually creating it.
I already know the sizes and the names of all the files that will go inside the archive.
I guess to have it easy, archive only, without compression.

How can I do that with a tar? Or is there any other archive format which can let me do that?

As a background:
I want to read a bunch of files from S3, tar/zip them.
And then, put it back in S3 as a new file.
I'd like to achieve this without using memory or disk.
So single-pass read-write fashion.

S3 however wants me to pass an exact content length,
hence the pre-calculation I'm asking for.
I can obtain the final size by generating the archive upfront using some /dev/null stream, then do the actual archiving again, but ideally I'd like to avoid that double reading.

Comment: You will need to use some memory to complete a S3->Tar->S3 pipeline, so you can just read in, say, 8 MiB chunks, and upload each chunk as part of a multipart upload, without needing to know the final size.

Comment: `multiplart` + `memory buffer` seems a legit idea. Thanks! Even better actually, using Zip/Gzip would be preferable with compression